# HOw To Show Data in Ms Chart on Mouse Over C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

i am using ms chat sp line i want that when i take my cursor to the chart to any point it will show the reading at that particular point as my chart is as

```
 DataView dv = dtGroupedBy.DefaultView;
                dv.Sort = "DATE";
                chart1.DataSource = dv;
                chart1.DataBind();

<asp:chart runat="server" ID="chart1" Height="432px" Width="923px" 
    style="margin-top: 0px">
<Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Spline" XValueMember="DATE" YValueMembers="POWER"
                    Color="LightGreen">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                    <AxisX Title="Days">
                    </AxisX>
                    <AxisY Title="Electricity in KW">
                    </AxisY>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
</asp:chart>
```

Hopes for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if asp chart provides tooltip on data points. If yes use it, else write custom div's for each point and image map to the html output after chart is being created.

Comment: in chart properties there is a tooltip option then how would i use tooltip??

Comment: See example http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2008/12/15/asp-net-3-5-charting-control-formatting-tooltips-as-date/

Comment: in this code in the load method ,                                     Chart1.Series["My series"].ToolTip = "X value \t= #VALX{d}\nY value \t= #VALY{C}\nRadius \t= #VALY2{P}"; from where x value and y value is bonding too??? In my case code above my chart is binding to the dataview how would i bind by data from data view to the tooltip X and Y ???

Comment: try it and check it. It picks x/y values from series

Comment: "my series could not be found in the series collection " this is the error i am getting :(

Comment: have you set the tooltip before adding series?

Comment: Element with the name my series could not be found in the series collection this the error i am getting when i set tooltip ???                My tool tip is:chart1.Series["My series"].ToolTip = "X value \t= #VALX{d}\nY value \t= #VALY{C}";

Comment: the code lines i mentioned above is working for me but not efficiently means that it shows data some where on the chart and getting load and some times getting hang ?? is there any thing to make it work efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

In your codebehind page try adding this when you load your chart:
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "#VALX, #VALY";

#VALX and #VALY are some of many variables described below that you can add to the tooltip.

http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1132